# four digit in the middle displayed as wildcard while user type the number

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am developing a Swing application which use JTextField to let user input telephone number. For security, the four digit in the middle need to be displayed as wildcard while user type the phone number. Meanwhile, this JTextField also show the four digit in the middle as wildcard when the phone number is from database.

How to customize the JTextField? Any help are highly appreciated.

Comment: Extend it and Override methods that dictate what get's rendered in terms of text/

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DocumentFilter`.

See this example, simply change `new PhoneNumberFilter(6,10,'*')` to your exact needs.

F.I South Africa has phone number which is 10 digits long, 
First 3 is dialling code and the rest the unique number.

So if want the last 4 digits to be masked with ***, and the entire phone number is 10 digits I do `new PhoneNumberFilter(6,10,'*')` to mark the last 4 (10-6=4).

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                //create instance of our custom DocumentFiler class
                PhoneNumberFilter phoneNumberFilter = new PhoneNumberFilter(6, 10, '*');


                JTextField jtf = new JTextField(10);
                //add filter to JTextField
                ((AbstractDocument) jtf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(phoneNumberFilter);
                frame.add(jtf);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                //jtf.setText("0119887654");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}

class PhoneNumberFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private int textLength = 0;//keeps track of length of text within the field (used to check if we should start applying the mask)
    private int numberMaskStartIndex;
    private int numberMaskEndIndex;
    private String mask;//what the characters in the specified ranges positions will be replaced with

    public PhoneNumberFilter(int start, int end, char mask) {
        numberMaskStartIndex = start;
        numberMaskEndIndex = end - 1;
        this.mask = String.valueOf(mask);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.length() > 1) {
            for (int n = string.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {//an inserted string may be more than a single character i.e copy and pasting a number
                char c = string.charAt(n);//get a single character of the string
                if (n >= numberMaskStartIndex && n <= numberMaskEndIndex) {//check if its between the range which we should mask
                    super.replace(fb, i, i1, mask, as);
                } else {
                    super.replace(fb, i, i1, String.valueOf(c), as);
                }
                textLength++;
            }
        } else if (textLength >= numberMaskStartIndex && textLength <= numberMaskEndIndex) {//only a singe character was inserted and its between the range which we should mask
            super.replace(fb, i, i1, mask, as);
            textLength++;
        } else {
            super.replace(fb, i, i1, string, as);
            textLength++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) throws BadLocationException {
        super.remove(fb, i, i1);
        if (i == 0 && i1 == textLength) {//if the text removed is the entire textfield i.e CTRL+A or Mouse dragged and DEL than we reset our counter which keeps track of the number of characters in the textfield
            textLength = 0;
        } else {//only a single character was deleted
            textLength--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int i, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(fb, i, string, as);
    }
}
```

I have not added functionality to restrict user input, thus anything can be entered, the above is more to show the logic needed for:

> For security, the four digit in the middle need to be displayed as
>   wildcard while user type the phone number. Meanwhile, this JTextField
>   also show the four digit in the middle as wildcard when the phone
>   number is from database

you might still ask will it work when gotten from database, yes, becuase the DocumentFilter also applies to `setText(..);`

Comment: @yhqian see updated code, left out a crucial else statement and incremented length wrongly (especially when `setText` is used). Fixed those small bugs in the updated code

Comment: PhoneNumberFilter  works fine with JTextField. It really helps, thanks a million. But when I apply PhoneNumberFilter to JFormattedTextField, it dosnt work.

Comment: @yhqian what is the `JFormattedField` for? restricting input to numeric only?

Comment: JFormattedField  work with MaskFormatter , can restrict input to numeric only, see  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html